# Avoid gson de-serialize json string to to LinkedHashMap class members

Tags: java, json, gson

Currently, if I want to avoid gson from de-serialize json string to `LinkedHashMap`, I would use the following code

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = gson.fromJson(json_string,  new TypeToken<HashMap<Integer, String>>(){}.getType());
```

However, I have the following class

```
public static class Inventory {
    public Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    public Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
}
```

If I use `Inventory result = gson.fromJson(json_string,  Inventory.class);`, my `Inventory` instance will have its class members as `LinkedHashMap`.

How can I enforce de-serialize json string, to have `HashMap` as class members?

Here's the working code example

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author yccheok
 */
public class Gson_tutorial {
    public static class Inventory {
        public Map<Integer, String> map1 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        public Map<Integer, String> map2 = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            Map<Integer, String> map= new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            map.put(2, "cake");

            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            final String json_string = gson.toJson(map);
            // {"2":"cake"}
            System.out.println(json_string);

            HashMap<Integer, String> result = gson.fromJson(json_string,  new TypeToken<HashMap<Integer, String>>(){}.getType());
            // class java.util.HashMap
            System.out.println(result.getClass());
        }

        {
            Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
            inventory.map1.put(2, "cake");
            inventory.map2.put(3, "donut");

            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
            final String json_string = gson.toJson(inventory);
            // {"map1":{"2":"cake"},"map2":{"3":"donut"}}
            System.out.println(json_string);

            Inventory result = gson.fromJson(json_string,  Inventory.class);
            // class java.util.LinkedHashMap
            System.out.println(result.map1.getClass());
            // class java.util.LinkedHashMap
            System.out.println(result.map2.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: LinkedHashMap is a subclass of HashMap, so if you're getting a LinkedHashMap then you already have a HashMap.  What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your fields as `HashMap`s. Short of doing that, you'll need to use a custom deserializer.

But if you're using `Map`, why do you care if it's a `LinkedHashMap` or a `HashMap`?

Comment: Inventory is a 3rd party library. In one of the functions of Inventory, it will perform casting from Map to HashMap

Comment: @CheokYanCheng Well that's not a great 3rd party library :(. Gson is not well suited for this. Consider using Jackson and its mixins.

Comment: @CheokYanCheng But HotLicks brings up a good point in their comment. A `LinkedHashMap` _is_ a `HashMap`. Are you getting some kind of `ClassCastException`?

Comment: So what's the solution here? I use gson.fromJson() with this json:  `{"accountID":"cbeeeec4-4599-4a33-9e72-8a90d5ccd0e1.1459692534305" ,"cash":{"cashAvailableForTrade":8789.01,"cashAvailableForWithdrawal":8789.01,"cashBalance":8789.01}}`.  `cash` is converted to `{cashAvailableForTrade=8789.01, cashAvailableForWithdrawal=8789.01, cashBalance=8789.01}`. How to avoid it & get `cash` as HashMap?

Comment: @shuwnyuantee I don't understand your question.